# How to Construct Nested JSON Message on Output Topic in KSQLDB

Tags: apache-kafka, ksqldb

from one of the source systems i received the below event payload

Created Stream1 for the below json payload

Event JSON 1

```
{
 "event": {
  "header": {
   "name":"abc",
   "version":"1.0",
   "producer":"123",
   "channel":"lab",
   "countryCode":"US"
  },
  "body":{"customerIdentifiers":[
   {"customerIdentifier":"1234","customerIdType":"cc"},
   {"customerIdentifier":"234","customerIdType":"id"}
  ],
  "accountIdentifiers":[
   {"accountIdentifier":"123","accountIdType":"no"},
   {"accountIdentifier":"Primary","accountIdType":"da"}
  ],
  "eventDetails":{
   "offeramount":"40000",
   "apr":"2.6%",
   "minpayment":"400",
   "status":"Approved"
  }
 }
}
```

Event JSON 2

```
{
 "event": {
  "header": {
   "name":"abc",
   "version":"1.0",
   "producer":"123",
   "channel":"lab",
   "countryCode":"US"
  },
  "body":{"customerIdentifiers":[
   {"customerIdentifier":"1234","customerIdType":"cc"},
   {"customerIdentifier":"234","customerIdType":"id"}
  ],
  "accountIdentifiers":[
   {"accountIdentifier":"123","accountIdType":"no"},
   {"accountIdentifier":"Primary","accountIdType":"da"}
  ],
  "eventDetails":{
   "offeramount":"70000",
   "apr":"3.6%",
   "minpayment":"600",
   "status":"Rejected"
  }
 }
}
```

I have created aggregation table on the the above stream1

```sql
CREATE TABLE EVENT_TABLE AS 
  SELECT 
    avg(minpayment) as Avg_MinPayment, 
    avg(apr) AS Avg_APr, 
    avg(offeramount) AS Avgofferamount , 
    status 
  FROM STREAM1 
  GROUP BY status 
  EMIT CHANGES;
```

```
Status | Avg_MinPayment | Avg_APr | Avgofferamount 
-----------------------------------------
Approved | 400 | 2.6% | 40000

Rejected | 600 | 3.6% | 70000
```

I got the above result from KTable and KTable Topic json look like this

Aggregate JSON1

PRINT 'EVENT_TABLE';

```
{
  "Status" : "Approved", 
  "Avg_Minpayment" : "400", 
  "Avg_APr" : "2.6%", 
  "offeramount" : "40000"
}
```

Aggregate JSON2

```
{
  "Status" : "Rejected", 
  "Avg_Minpayment" : "600", 
  "Avg_APr" : "3.6%", 
  "offeramount" : "70000"
}
```

But i have to Construct and publish the final target json on output topic like below json format. i have to add the header and body to the aggregate json1 and aggregate json2.

```
{
 "event":{
  "header":{
   "name":"abc",
   "version":"1.0",
   "producer":"123",
   "channel":"lab",
   "countryCode":"US"
  },
  "body":{
   "Key":[
{"Status":"approved","Avg_Minpayment":"400","Avg_APr":"2.6%","offeramount":"40000"},
{"Status":"rejected","Avg_Minpayment":"600","Avg_APr":"3.6%","offeramount":"70000"}
  ]
 }
}
```

Comment: Please [format your code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks) to make things easier for users in the future =)

Comment: It would also help if your example worked. For example, your sql uses `avg(salary)`, but there is no `salary` in your source data.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have enough information to comment more. Your required output seems to be grouping multiple inputs together. But you've not explained how you want them grouped, or provided sufficient example input.  Provide a more detailed description of your problem and I may be able to help.

Comment: @AndrewCoates. that is  sample data i might miss the salary but main problem is i will get the aggregation data like this {"Status" : "Approved", "Avg_Sal" : "10000", "Avg_APr" : "3.6%", "offeramount" : "40000"} and i want add header and repeated attributes to the final output json data. how can i build the json

Comment: For Header attributes i can add any static values it is just for structure only {"header":{"name":"abc","version":"1.0","producer":"123","channel":"lab","countryCode":"US"}....  want to add this header to my aggregated results json. is there any way to concatenate? or any solution to structure whole json in streams?

Comment: It's still not clear what you're trying to do.  There is data in your required output that doesn't exist in your example input. `$.event.body.Key` is an array. I understand where the first element in the row comes from, as I can see the data in the example source. But where does the second element come from? It's not in the source data...

Comment: I have updated the input and output jsons. now input and output data is on sink.  i want to create the final output json. thanks in advance..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not terribly clear what you're trying to achieve, given that your example SQL won't produce the example output, given then example input.  In fact your example SQL would fail with unknown column errors.

Something like the following *would* generate your example output:

```sql
CREATE TABLE EVENT_TABLE AS 
  SELECT 
    status,
    avg(eventDetails->minpayment) as Avg_MinPayment, 
    avg(eventDetails->apr) AS Avg_APr, 
    avg(eventDetails->offeramount) AS Avgofferamount
  FROM STREAM1 
  GROUP BY status 
  EMIT CHANGES;
```

Next, your example output...

```
Status | Avg_MinPayment | Avg_APr | Avgofferamount 
-----------------------------------------
Approved | 400 | 2.6% | 40000

Rejected | 600 | 3.6% | 70000
```

...is outputting one row per status. Yet, the output you say you want to achieve ...

```
{
 "event":{
  "header":{
   "name":"abc",
   "version":"1.0",
   "producer":"123",
   "channel":"lab",
   "countryCode":"US"
  },
  "body":{
   "Key":[
{"Status":"approved","Avg_Minpayment":"400","Avg_APr":"2.6%","offeramount":"40000"},
{"Status":"rejected","Avg_Minpayment":"600","Avg_APr":"3.6%","offeramount":"70000"}
  ]
 }
}
```

...contains both statuses, i.e. its combining both of your example input messages into a single output.

If I'm understanding you correctly, and you do indeed want to output the above JSON, then:

You would first need to include the `event` information. But which event information?  If you *know* they're always going to be the same, then you can use:

```sql
CREATE TABLE EVENT_TABLE AS 
  SELECT 
    status,
    latest_by_offset(event) as event,
    avg(eventDetails->minpayment) as Avg_MinPayment, 
    avg(eventDetails->apr) AS Avg_APr, 
    avg(eventDetails->offeramount) AS Avgofferamount
  FROM STREAM1 
  GROUP BY status 
  EMIT CHANGES;
```

The `latest_by_offset` aggregate function will capture the `event` information from the last message it saw.  Though I'm not convinced this is what you want. Could you not be getting other `rejected` and `accepted` messages with *different* `event` information?  If it is the `event` information that identifies which messages should be grouped together, then something like this might give you something close to what you want:

```sql
CREATE TABLE EVENT_TABLE AS 
  SELECT 
    event,
    collect_list(eventDetails) as body
  FROM STREAM1 
  GROUP BY event 
  EMIT CHANGES;
```

If this is close, then you may want to use the `STRUCT` constructor and `AS_VALUE` function to restructure your output.  For example:

```sql
CREATE TABLE EVENT_TABLE AS 
  SELECT 
    event as key,
    AS_VALUE(event) as event,
    STRUCT(
      keys := collect_list(eventDetails)
    ) as body
  FROM STREAM1 
  GROUP BY event 
  EMIT CHANGES;
```